# Meaning of "He was quite sane but abhorred conversation"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please help me, I don't get the drift of bold part in the sentence below.

> The father himself did not complain about the omission. On the day of
>   the funeral, which was very fine, he headed out of town as he would
>   have done ordinarily on a day he had decided not to spend at Douds. He
>   was wearing a felt hat and a long coat that would do for a rug if he
>   wanted to take a nap. His overshoes were neatly held on his feet with
>   the rubber rings from sealing jars. He was going out to fish for
>   suckers. The season hadn't opened yet, but he always managed to be a
>   bit ahead of it. He fished through the spring and early summer and
>   cooked and ate what he caught. He had a frying pan and a pot hidden
>   out on the riverbank. The pot was for boiling corn that he snatched
>   out of the fields later in the year, when he was also eating the fruit
>   of wild apple trees and grapevines. **He was quite sane but abhorred
>   conversation**. He could not altogether avoid it in the weeks following
>   his son's death, but he had a way of cutting it short.
>
> <sub>"Casting away" by Alice munro</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's

> *He was quite sane but (he) abhorred conversation.*

Comment: One more question :) Is this kind of omission a common practice.

Comment: I've seen similar omissions in other novels, so I believe that this kind of omission is quite common.

Comment: You can describe it as a coordination of predicates without positing ellipsis, if you like: *He [ [ was quite sane ] but [ abhorred conversation ] ] .  He [ [ liked cheese ] but [ hated milk ] ] .*